# Select value of nested element

Tags: jquery

I have nested elements:

```
<ul class="level-1">
  <li class="item-i">I</li>
  <li class="item-ii">II
    <ul class="level-2">
      <li class="item-a">A</li>
      <li class="item-b">B
        <ul class="level-3">
          <li class="item-1">1</li>
          <li class="item-2">2</li>
          <li class="item-3">3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-c">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>
```

How to get value (it's '1') from `li class="item-1">1</li>` when clicked? I have problem with defining right selector... How to end with something like this:

```
$(all children of level-1).click(function() {
    alert($(this.item-1").val(););
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

`$(this).text()`   OR  `$(this).html()`

`.val()` is for input fields.. So you cannot access the data you seek using `.val()`

```
$('.level-1 li').on('click', function(e) {

    alert($(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3
    }).text());
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Don't forget `e.stoppropagation()`   .. Otherwise you will also see the text inside the parent li..

[Try FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3z3Th/4/)

Comment: click on `II` and you'll see a bug :)

Comment: @ZoltanToth.. Fixed it .. Check Post

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felipekm/YyV4L/) with some tests, I guess this supply your need

Here is what I did:

```
$('.level-3').children('.item-1').css('color', 'red');​
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".level-1 li").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Please read up on jQuery events and selectors:
http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page